# how get data from subscribe and display to screen view using data binding

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, subscribe

first what I want to do or try to do is use a menu bar with options and use the values ​​to filter depending on that value, then how I do it.

`component 1` here is the menu bar, `component 2` is the list that I want to filter, I use a service for communication between the components and it works well. the problem is that the data I try to obtain from `component 1` is undefined outside the function of subscribe and I can not use it to filter the list.

```
this.communicationService.communication $ .subscribe ((data) => {
    data === this.x;
    console.log (data) // throw the expected data.
});
```

that's how I get the data from `component 1` now when I give console data to perfect data there is communication between the components and everything but when I want to use `this.x` to filter the data `this.x` comes out `undefined`

When I try to do this, it does not throw any data at me.

```
this.result = this.listingAFilter.filter ((f) => {
    return f.opcion === this.x
});
```

and I have even tried to do this but without result

```
this.communicationService.communication $ .subcribe (data => {
    this.result = this.listingAFilter.filter (f => {
        return f.opcion === data;
    })
})
```

Any help with this please, thanks for the help you can give me to solve this problem.

I'm Using Angular 6 and I have a list in one component and want to filter another list on another component depending on the result for the first list. I am using a service to communicate between components.

First Component (parent) communicate to service..

```
    commun(value) {
        this.cummunicationService.cummFunc(value);
    }
```

in service

```
    commFunc(commun: any) {
        this.Communication.next(commun);
        console.log(commun);
      }
```

and the second component (child) receive the message and try to filter the list depending on messages and printed in screen view, actually I got an empty list

```
this.communicationService.communication$.subscribe(
    data => this.result = this.list.filter( function(mo) {
        return mo.parentId === data.toString();
    })
);
```

I expecting to throw the result to screen and when I change the value on the list in parent component the result list change, I don't get an error message

Comment: Would you mind creating a demo code on https://stackblitz.com ? The answer requires better code visualization and not small chunks .

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are not correctly assigning the data variable to "x".

instead of this:

```js
this.communicationService.communication$.subscribe((data) => {
    data === this.x; // Here you are comparing to variables
    console.log (data) // throw the expected data.
});
```

do this:

```js
this.communicationService.communication$.subscribe((data) => {
    this.x = data; // Now you are assigning data to x
    console.log (data); // throw the expected data.
});
```